# How to Create a gradual fadeout signature in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I want to create a signature line like the attached picture with Photoshop:

[image: Faded text]

I asked the photographer who has this signature, and he said following are the steps:

1. basically I created a layer for background of the text
2. and selected the edge of the layer
3. feathered the selection by about 25 px and then deleted
4. that gave the fadeout feel

I couldn't figure out the head and tail of it...Can someone please help with the exact steps? It will also be a great help if someone can point out a PSD for this...

Comment: Welcome to GD.SE. The explanation is pretty understandable (I might do it that way or might not). Which part of it do you not know how to do? The [background](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-fill-a-selection-with-a-solid-color-in-phot.html)? [Selecting](http://www.photoshopessentials.com/basics/selections/rectangular-marquee-tool/)? [Feathering](http://www.photoshopessentials.com/basics/selections/feather-quick-mask/)? You could consider showing what you tried to do and where it got you. This helps to show that this is not a **"please work for free"** kind of question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this exactly as you've requested:

You will need two layers, one is the document background and one has your signature on it.

Next, hold cmd (Mac) or ctrl (windows) and click on the thumbnail image of the signature in the layers panel, this will highlight the edges of the signature. Alternatively you can right click the layer and choose Select Pixels.

Now, choose Select >> Modify >> Feather from the top menu bar.

Enter 25px on the dialog box that appears.

Now you want to inverse the selection with Select >> Inverse from the menu, this will highlight the rest of the image instead of the signature body. Now when you hit delete it will remove the edges of the signature.

Once done, you can mess with the opacity of the layer to get the desired effect.

Comment: Yes. However, you would not know if this is enough for the user as there is no indication of where he is stuck. So might be that he i struggling with step -1 how to make the overlay part. The explanation is perfectly fine if you know how to do basic things. So if you want to answer this fully you should start there. It would be better if the OP could clarify the real problem

Comment: Duly noted JooJaa, if the problem is in step one, I will of course amend my answer to be more descriptive in that area

Comment: Thank you so much abbott567 and @joojaa... I was stuck in deleting the feather selection part (It was deleting the feathered selection, it didn't crossed my mind that I had to inverse it!!! ). I understand that I should have talked about it in my original question, and I apologize for it.

Comment: No problem! Happy to have helped =)

Answer (score 1):

I think on other hand, instead of deleting the layer by setting up a feather value, I would approach the same by non-destructive method.

Using the layer mask. 
Once you have designed the background panel, apply layer mask. 
And use the gradient to to get the soft finish merging effect.
You can also transform the mask, by unlinking it from layer.

Below is the sample image I quickly created.
[image]

Comment: I dont understand why my 10 reputation points were ripped off!

Comment: pzv, this is awesome. I tried it and the result just looks good as what @abbott567 replied. One question though... How did you get the white border, since the gradient effects the background panel as a whole...

Comment: The white border is on same layer hence its getting affected. You can **apply stroke** to the grey panel to get that white border or you can simply **fill the marquee** selection with white of same dimension. Hope this helps. Don't forget to vote up if my answer is helpful ;-)